# Docker Network Interfaces Not Appearing in WSL Ubuntu or Windows CMD/Powershell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network

I am currently embroiled in a project that leverages tools such as Docker, docker-compose, and other networking components. I set up a docker-compose file with Docker networks of bridge type, but I'm encountering a hiccup. When I execute the **ip addr** command to list network interfaces in WSL Ubuntu 22.04 (which is running on a Windows environment), the interfaces pertaining to the Docker networks are conspicuously absent. It's worth noting that I'm also unable to view these interfaces using **ipconfig** in **CMD** and **Powershell**.

Here's a breakdown of the steps I've undertaken:

1. Crafted Docker networks with the subsequent specifications:
   -trusted_network: 10.10.10.0/24
   -untrusted_network: 200.200.200.0/24
   -interco_network: 125.168.1.0/24

2.I have used the **docker network inspect** command to verify the networks are up and running correctly.

3.Tried to list all network interfaces using the **ip addr**, **ifconfig**, **ipconfig** commands.

**Expected Result:**

I anticipated seeing the Docker network interfaces listed alongside other existing network interfaces.

**Actual Result:**

The Docker network interfaces are not showing up.

I'm aiming to utilize a tool like Wireshark to monitor traffic on a specific network such as the **trusted_network** established in docker-compose. Would anyone be able to shed light on the situation and suggest any potential solutions or steps I might have overlooked?